# How do I set workflow which starts when value changes?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I hope someone can help me with my issue I cant manage to solve. I am using SharePoint 2010 and SP Designer to create a workflow.

My questions is how can I create a workflow which starts upon status value in Status column changes in document library? I need two different workflows to be automatically started depending on selected value in the Status.

My status column has following options:

- Draft (no workflow required)
- For review (feedback workflow required)
- For approval (approval workflow required)

  Workflow to be started as following:

**1st step :** When user changes the value in Status to "For review" the Feedback workflow will start automatically and sent out the email notification to initiator and receiver with the instructions what to do and upon completion email notification with completion message will be sent to all.

**2nd step:** when user changes the value in Status to "For approval" the Approval workflow stats automatically and sent out the email notifications to initiator and receiver and again upon completion email will be sent out to initiator and receiver.

I have tried following but the workflow doesn’t work
the following actions will run parallel:

> If current item:Status equals For Review  Start Feedback process on
> Current Item with these users
>
> If current Item:Status equals For Approval  Start Approval process on
> Current Item with these users

I have also tried Else if with the same structure and also separating the above ifs to different steps, non of it works and I am not sure how to create such a workflow which will automatically do what I need.

Comment: just one question, do you have tasks also in this?

Comment: assume so... as approval and feedback workflow are based on tasks. I am using predefined workflows which are standard in SPD when you use the action "start approval process" or "start Feedback process"

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your respond.

Is it possible to merge the two workflows into one, saying using the “Wait for item to change”

Sot the workflow would look like this:

[image]

I am not sure if this is the right way how to write the workflow as I am not very familiar with it.

Or do you have to have 2 different workflows assigned to the list and in each you will have the function “Wait for item to Change” before you start the workflow?

Many thanks for the respond.

Helena

Comment: There is no reason why you couldn't do the above.  It would work just fine.  I had suggested two workflows because the way you described it, you made it sound like you wanted to separate out the processes.

Comment: Thanks David, only Issue is that the workflow is pending and Waiting on Status even though I do change the status, it still shows as pending. Any idea why?

Comment: Not off the top of my head.  Does it occur at the first stage or second stage?  Does it happen all the time?  The only time I have seen this happen is when the field I was attaching to was a checkbox.  I usually attach to a drop down box.  Is the field you are attaching to a drop down or a text field?

Comment: - Status field is drop down field.
- changed the workflow setting to start workflow automatically when an item is created and changed, before it was also covering manual start (which I do not want – my mistake)
- now the workflow works for review only, not picking up the approval workflow.

Comment: hmm, I don't know if this is a limitation on the SharePoint 2010 WF engine.  The reason I say that, is because I have a SP 2013 WF that has about 4 wait for value to change and it works fine for all of them.  It is not ideal, but could you possibly break it out into two WFs.  One that looks for the review and one that looks for the For Approval.  When the review is complete, it updates the field to the required value which releases the second WF.  I am curious if the 2010 WF simply has issues with two "waits" on the same field in the same WF.  It may not be able to add a second listener

Comment: to the same field.  It may however be ok if two WF have a listener on the same field as they are two separate instances.

Comment: suppose that I will have to split it to two workflows... as it seems that if the review is completed, and I change the status field for approval it terminates the approval workflow without any notification

Comment: Yah.  I don't know why it does that in 2010.  I haven't worked with this particular functionality much in SP2010.  I should test to see if the same thing happens in 2013.  When I said above that it worked fine, that was against different fields in the item, not the same field like you are attempting.

Comment: I split the workflows and all works well workflows are sending emails as required.

What I have noticed is that if you fire for review (feedback) workflow it also shows in Approval workflow status as "In Progress". Why is it?

Comment: If you set things up as I described, it will actually be starting both workflows.  So although the Approval WF is waiting for the value it actually started at the same time, hence the In Progress message.

Comment: I see the point now. I have now managed to change the “in progress” status.

One more question, if I start Approval workflow as 1st step, the Feedback is terminated with Completed status, how can I avoid this? For Example, even though the user approves the document and it can be final version, it still need to be sent for review to the users, therefore I would expect to have For Review workflow status empty because the For review wf did not happen. In simply way if I do not start one of the workflow I want the WF status to be empty.
Is there any way how to do it? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Sorry Helena.  I know of no way short of custom code in event receivers to do something like that, and not even sure that would work.  If you have two workflows running it's going to display the status in the column, even if one is sitting idle.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past for this is not to try and figure out how to start a WF depending on the value, but have the WF actually kick off immediately, but wait until the value changes on a particular column before continuing on.

In SP Designer 2010 you have the option to have the WF wait.  The action is called "Wait for Field Change in Current Item".  You can then set the column you want it to wait for, the operator (ex. To equal, to not equal, to be empty, etc) and the value for the comparison.

So basically what I would do in your situation is when the item is added, kick off two workflows.  One for "review" and one for "approval".  Immediately on start, log that the WF has started and is waiting for the value in  to change to .  The next step is simply adding the action Wait for Field Change in Current Item.  Set the values to Status, to equal, "" (sorry, I don't have 2010 installed so don't have screen shots).  Do this for both WFs.  Once the status is updated, the WFs will then continue on, when the values they are waiting for are set.

Please note, this does increase the risk of WFs sitting there indefinitely if the item is never updated so you may want to create a view on the status field to monitor  when the item has been sitting there for a while with no updates and monitor the view periodically.

Hope this helps,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

After your Current item is *reviewed*, why not just have the approval start automatically after the review, without the "**Wait for Status to equal for Approval**." By taking that statement out the approval will only begin right after the review.  I have that for my workflow which is an Approval and then Review and works fine.

** I enabled "Request Change" in SharePoint Desighner 2010 for any changes to be made and until they are made and accepted it will not automically shift to the next step. **

Comment: good point and great solution, but not all of the document will be sent for review, some might be sent directly for approval, therefore I was requesting 2 workflows for same field

Comment: Got it ! Then yes my way does not make sense what you could try now is an Else If Statement. If "___" Field is Review then start Review Process Else if "______" is Approve then start Approve Process and paralell to that you can make it that when the status field is changed it goes through the process you prescribe it to.